# PHP empty variable inside condition

Tags: php

I have a condition in which it is using a variable to pull either a number through 0-17, the string "MAKEUP", or the variable will be empty. I would like it to output the text "WIN" if the variable is greater than the number 8 and "LOSS" if the variable is less than the number 9. I would also like it to out "MAKEUP" if the variable consist of the string MAKEUP, and to display nothing if the variable is empty. Seems pretty simple to me, but I'm having issues particularly with the empty part. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here? Code below

```
    <?php
    $t1w8 = '';
    $result = $t1w8;
    if ($result > 8 && !empty($result)) {
        echo 'WON';
    } elseif ($result < 9 && !empty($result)) {
        echo 'LOSS';
    } elseif ($result == 'MAKEUP') {
        echo '-';
    } else {
        echo 'yooo';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is your issue here?

Comment: First, you need to test `!empty()` before trying to test its value. For example: `if (!empty($result) && $result > 8)`

Comment: var dump your $result

Comment: so your case its ecoying LOSS right?

Comment: And why not using just `$t1w8` ?

Comment: Also worth to remember that empty() considers variable with value of 0 integer as empty, ie. FALSE.

Comment: !empty will always be true if the preceding statement is also true, making it pointless.

Comment: explain your condition `>8 and <9` more

Comment: if the $t1w8 variable contains a number of 0-8, it should echo a LOSS, if it contains a number of 9+, it should echo LOSS, if it contains the word MAKEUP, it should display a dash symbol -, if it is empty it should remain empty. Problem has been if it's been empty, it shows as a LOSS. I'm guessing because PHP is making it NULL?

Comment: @DocWeird, how can I get around that? I would need it to display the actual number 0 if that was the case

Comment: @teeyo because I actually have several variables that will need to fit into this configuration, and rather than change 5 per line I just change 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some changes in your conditions like this

```
<?php
    //$result = "MAKEUP";
    $result = 0;
    if ($result === 'MAKEUP') {
        echo '-';
    }else if (is_numeric($result) && $result < 9 ) {
        echo 'LOSS';
    }else if (is_numeric($result) && $result >= 9 ) {
        echo 'WON';
    } else{
        echo 'yooo';
    }
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/897120

Comment: This seems to work for the most part, only one thing is if the $result = the number 0, it does not work correctly, displaying the "yooo" text instead

Comment: @stoggafu : What you want for value `0`

Comment: That is_numeric did it. Thank you, sir!

Comment: what happens if the number is 1234232345231232? That is a WIN?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes. My variables will only ever go up to 17.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
<?php

//$result = "MAKEUP";
$result = "";
//$result = "9";
//$result = "-";

if ($result == 'MAKEUP' && !empty($result) ) {
    echo '-';
} elseif ($result > 8 && !empty($result)) {
    echo 'WON';
} elseif ($result <= 8 && !empty($result)) {
    echo 'LOSS';
} else {
    echo 'yooo';
}
?>
```

for demo :[demo code here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e639d6ff25ac058125690caf689f0f3882a18ce6)

Comment: Your condition is not matching with OP condition, <9 would be `loss`, >8 would be 'won', text `MAKEUP` would give `-` else `yooo`

Comment: but how it codition like >8 win and <9 loss

Comment: I think 0-8 would be `loss` and >8 means 9,10,11... would be `won`

Comment: correct, anything below 9 is a loss and anything above 8 is a win. However, when the variable is set to the number "0" it is displaying the alternative "yooo" text.

Comment: Thank you, but that will not work correctly either. When removing the !empty, if the $result variable is empty, it will display as 'LOSS', instead of yooo

Comment: @Bhargav that's basically the same code I came here with though. The problem with it that way is 0 shows up as yooo. Try making result 0. 0 should show LOSS

Comment: because `0 is a empty type` so its not check in `!empty` so you manually check for 0 like `$result>=0 && $result<=8` in condition @stoggafu

Answer (score 0):

You have explained that your number range is from 0-17.
You have also explained that you could get the word MAKEUP.

Based upon those constraints we could use something like this

```
$output = "";
// Do we have something?
if(strlen($result) > 0) {
    if (strtolower($result) == "makeup") {
        $output = "MAKEUP";
    }
    // assumes a single digit string
    else if ($result < 9) {
        $output = "LOSS";
    } else if ($result <= 17) {
        $output = "WIN";
    }
}
echo $output;
```